# Can we create multiple pages in a single applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

Is it possible in a Java applet that when user clicks a button, he is guided to some another page on same applet (just as we are guided to different pages on a browser using HTML), while the data on previous page is being preserved?

If yes, then what are the methods that can fulfill such functionality?

Answer (score 2):

If below is what you mean, you can do it by using `JTabbedPane`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Java applets are fully featured applications (running in a security sandbox).

You can use a UI Framework and use buttons and tab panes to switch between contents.

Have a look at JavaFX: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm
which is the Rich UI framework for java nowadays.

P.S. If you need to switch between HTML pages, where each page contains an applet. You'll need to pass arguments to each of the applets in order to keep state.

Answer (score 1):

Swing or AWT components?  (I suggest use Swing, and based on that..)

- The closest thing to what you are asking is using a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).  See also [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).
- As [mentioned above by @smiche2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27942806/418556) there is also [`JTabbedPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html).  See [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) for detals and working code.